# Remove Zeros from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What would be the best Regex pattern to use in order to remove some zeroes (not all) from a random string. The rule is to remove only the ones after the letters, example:

- TST00432505 should yield TST432505

Comment: Try using the pattern `/[a-z]0+/gi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
$outputstring = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])0+/i', '', $inputstring);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/          : regex delimiter
(?<=[a-z]) : positive lookbehind, assumes there is a letter before
0+         : one or more zeros
/i         : regex delimiter and modifier case insensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression based string replacement should do the job:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/^([^0]+)(0*)(.+)$/', '\\1\\3', 'TST00432505');
```

The output obviously is:

```
TST432505
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that some strings will come without zeroes and these ones will have to be ignored

Comment: I updated the question accordingly. Though I would expect you to be able to adjust the pattern yourself, actually.